# CDC processes all 9999 requests at once. Is this by design or a bug?

Tags: apex, platform-event, asynchronous, change-data-capture

In salesforce documentation batch size of platform event is mentioned as 2000 maximum ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm)). Which it definitely follows (tested). But for CDC its not mentioned. I also tried this in my dev org.

I created this CDC event.

`ARecord__ChangeEvent`

And wrote a small trigger to check the batch size.

```
trigger ARecordAsyncEvent on ARecord__ChangeEvent (after insert) {

    List<ARecord__ChangeEvent> aRecordChangeEvents = Trigger.new;
    List<String> aRecordChangeEventsStrings = new List<String>();
    for(ARecord__ChangeEvent aRecordChangeEvent : aRecordChangeEvents){
        aRecordChangeEventsStrings.addAll(aRecordChangeEvent.ChangeEventHeader.getRecordIds());
    }

    System.debug('size is -> ' + aRecordChangeEventsStrings.size());
}
```

So for anonymous apex.

```
List<ARecord__c> lstARecords = new List<ARecord__c>();

for (Integer i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
    lstARecords.add(new ARecord__c(Name='TestMe123',RecordTypeId='0127F000000hwtzQAA'));
}

insert lstARecords;
```

The output printed was.

```
04:17:51.0 (6582339)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|size is -> 9999
```

Which means CDC tries to process all 9999 records in same transaction which can lead to **governor limits being hit easily.**

This seems to be missing in CDC documentation which is a pitfall for people who may be implementing CDC assuming it follows the same 2k batch by default as per Platform event.
Do we have any documentation related to this in salesforce?

Comment: The docs agree that the limit should be 2k. I've [asked for clarification](https://twitter.com/brianmfear/status/1574370753851535360). In the meantime, have you tried [explicitly setting your batch size](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm)? Does that fix your issue?

Comment: @sfdcfox But this is CDC. Where do we configure batch size in CDC?

Comment: Update your PlatformEventSubscriberConfig using the Tooling API, see [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm).

Comment: @sfdcfox I saw this, but I think its not possible to fetch `PlatformEventConsumerId` for CDC, which is a required field for updating `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig`

Comment: @NagendraSingh Did you found any solution on this. I need to process an object which is through bulk upload and do further.  Since DML also has a limit we want to get data in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a discussion with our Salesforce Product team, there is no limit on the number of records in a batch handled by the trigger, only a limit on the number of events.

From [Merged Change Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_subscribe_merged_events.htm)

> For efficiency, sometimes change events for one transaction are merged into one event if the same change occurred in multiple records of the same object type during one second.
> When change events are merged, Salesforce sends one change event for all affected records and the recordIds field contains the IDs for all records that have the same change.

Considering your current scenario, which is generating equivalent events with data, all the same, we are merging events so that a single event represents multiple record IDs. Note that in your change event trigger you are counting the number of recordIds, not the number of change events.

You could check the size of aRecordChangeEvents, or you could randomize the record name so that events will not be merged.

For example, I tried this for creating records and could see Salesforce does merge change events on insert

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
    Integer randomNumber = Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 10000));
    lstARecords.add(new ARecord__c(Name='TestMe_' + randomNumber,RecordTypeId='0127F000000hwtzQAA'));
}
```

Let me know incase of any follow up queries

Comment: So if a dataload, of 50k, is done on an object, where CDC is enabled, and all the are having same changes. And in 1 second if the system consumes 20k records,  then the code should be able to handle those many record Ids at once. Which will `90%` lead to Apex CPU time limit.

Comment: Another follow up question :  Why are there events merged only in CDC and not in case of Platform events?

Comment: I'll check and update on these. Thanks

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @NagendraSingh Apologies for the delay. I've reached out internally on these points. In the scenario you mentioned, the CPU limit would likely be reached, the suggestion here is to add some variation to the data load. We don't guarantee that merging will happen for change events. The conditions that would lead to merging cannot be controlled by an end user to cause merging of events.
Let me know if you'd like to understand anything specific so that I can ask the concerned team. Thanks